# Formatting a double with decimals C#

Tags: c#, formatting, double, decimal

Is it possible to format a `double`, so he doesn't chance the text 2140.76 to 214076 but instead letting it be 2140.76?

I can't use ',' for the decimal numbers, since the entire text file that I'm reading are numbers using '.' for separating the decimals, 10000 records, every day, so ...

**EDIT:**

```
double natMB = 0;
boolean check = double.TryParse(splitline[8], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out natMB);
if (check == false)
{
   natMB = 0;
}
else
{
   natMB = natMB * 1024;
}

double intMB = 0;
boolean check2 = double.TryParse(splitline[9], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out intMB);
if (check2==false)
{
   intMB=0;
}
else
{
   intMB = intMB * 1024;
}
```

The 0 value is necessary since I need to enter these values in an SQL statement, and they need to show up as 0, not as null.

Comment: Do you know, that in some countries default separator for fraction part is comma, in other countries dot? This is called Culture Settings.

Comment: I did not know about culture settings, but now I do! I'm still here to learn ... :s

Comment: So be careful with number, date and time formats. They may be diffrent in systems with diffrent language. For example - in my country default fraction separator is ",". In USA there is 12-hour time format (and you can't simply sort strings with time represented like this).

Comment: Show us sample of text that you trying to parse. Maybe there is better way. By the way - you can reduce your code. Use:

if (double.TryParse(splitline[8], out natMB)) // instead of using variable.

Comment: Added my way of doing it now, it should be doubles, the input is megabyte, the output is kilobyte (the 1024)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, Do you want to parse a double from a string with dot decimal separator ?

If yes try with this :

```
double.Parse("2140.76", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the invariant culture to format a number with a decimal period, regardless of your local culture settings:

```
string formatted = someDouble.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start reading here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx

Basically, you create an `NumberFormatInfo` that you can customise to use with `String.Format` to use any format you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to format a double so he doesn't chance the text 2140.76 to 214076 but instead 
>   letting it be 2140.76?

Yes. Let me play ignorant - I have no idea how you can even ask that and have the poroblem given the extensive formatting methods.

> I can't use ',' for the decimal numbers, since the entire text file that i'm reading are numbers 
>   using '.' for separating the decimals, 10000 records, every day, so ...

So the problem likely is that you ahve a culture issue at hand and an ignorant developer on the other side. Ignorant because files exchagned should always be english formatted always, to avoid that.

Anyhow, basically:
* Change your culture info in the thread to english or
* Use english culture info for parsing and text generation.

Read the documentation for the methods you use -there areo verlaods that allow you to tune the formatting.

Comment: "files exchagned should always be english formatted always", uhm shouldn't that be `InvariantCulture` formatted?

Comment: InvariantCulture yes, but that IS english mostly... and the problem is if you write a file for exahgne and tell someone it is InvariantCulture you may get a blank look as this is a .NET specific term. And you can not assume on file exchanges that the people know .NET terms ;) So, I prefer using english - so a Java or C++ programmer does not get me that blank look when the brain goes into google mode ;)

Comment: I can sympathize with your reasoning, however (maybe because I'm not a US citizen ;-), I still find it difficult. For example, there are different "english" cultures (.NET or not) and there are even [differences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2329317/21567) between "invariant" and `en-US` (which I assume you refer to) cultures. Notably the 24-hour vs. 12-hour format. In general I have learned to make every assumption in a file (interface) explicit. Including but not limited to number formats and especially about the character set allowed (but I digress from the OP's question now ;-)