# DateTime.ToString() not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

In the screenshot DateTime.ToString() method is being called but the date is not getting formatted in expected format (as seen in Quick Watch widnow). Is something wrong ?

[image]

Comment: You are giving it an explicit format and then expecting it to use the regional one?

Comment: Yeah. Looks like epic programmer fail. You do NOT call "ToString()", you call an overload that says exactly how you want this one formatted.

Comment: What format do you want it in?

Comment: No, I am expecting to get the format that is specified as parameter to ToString method. Showing the regional format just in case they are having any effect on the output.

Comment: @Brij Oh, so you are referring to the slashes turning into hyphens?

Comment: I want the date to be in the format as explicitly specified !!!

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, yes you are correct, slashes are turning into hyphens.

Comment: @Brij I am simply trying to make your question clearer, the screenshot is very small and truth be told, not entirely needed. You could have shown expected output versus actual and it would have been clearer.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, I had the same confusion. The question was not very clear.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Picture ain't that small. I am in Chrome, and can use Open in new tab and it is pretty good..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `/` as separator in your `ToString` format. But your current culture seems to has `-` as date separator. That is why you see the difference. You can pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` with `ToString`.

Like:

```
DateTimeObject.ToString("MM/dd/yyy HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: and we gotta winner.. +1

Comment: @Habib, why did the `/` turn into `-`. Why are they being changed internally, despite being specified explicitly ?

Comment: @Brij [Here is the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

Comment: @Brij, Sriram, has pointed to the right documentation, but just to add a one more thing, When you don't specify the culture in `ToString` then the current culture is used. You may see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329297/net-are-there-any-differences-between-invariantculture-and-en-us

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.ToString` replaces `/` with the current date separator and `:` with the current time separator. You're passing in the format yourself, and it does not match what's in the Region settings.

To use the Region settings, use `ToShortDateString()` and `ToShortTimeString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
   DateTime.now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

or

```
   DateTime.now.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy");
```