# Converting float to the currency string

Tags: c#

I'm not able to convert float to the currency string. I tried to find an answer on the internet.

```
float price = 29.95f;
Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("C"));
```

Outputs:

```
29,95 ?
```

P.S. Problem is with my console.

Comment: And does the codepage of your console support the currency symbol for your current culture? I would hazard a guess that the conversion is fine, it is `Console.WriteLine` and the console running your program that is at flaw here, it doesn't have a proper symbol for the currency symbol and thus just displays a question mark instead.

Comment: *Which* culture is this for by the way?

Comment: Incidentally, the `float` type is not often accurate enough for money. The `decimal` type is, and should be used.

Comment: Also best to double check your currency symbol in Control Panel \ Region - in case for whatever reason it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in comments by Lasse, you may be missing a culture:

Try:

```
Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

For a specific culture, you can try:

```
price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB")); // for uk culture..
```

decimal is usually the recommendation for currency.

See more here:

[Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency/3730040#3730040)

Comment: Frequently I use InvariantCulture to avoid culture conflicts. 
Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Comment: i wouldnt use. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329297/net-are-there-any-differences-between-invariantculture-and-en-us

Comment: the currency symbol differs.

Comment: what exception are u getting

Comment: Can you change it to Cultureinfo.

Comment: You are missing the using.. Right click the CultureInfo, Use the light bubble. or add `using System.Globalization;` on the top of your file

Answer (score 0):

You should use `decimal` instead of `float` for currency because it is more accurate. Anyway your code is fine and it must be a display error.

```
// Declare price as a decimal.
decimal price = 29.95m;
```

You can also specify cultures using:

```
// For German culture.
Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-DE")));

// Output
// 29,95 €

// For British culture.
Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB")));

// Ouput
// £29.95

// For American culture.
Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US")));

// Output
// $29.95
```

**Edit:** Just saw your update, glad it was just a display issue. Also, I think you should give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a read. It is better to accept an answer (even if you have to leave your own) rather than edit your post.