# Force string interpolation to always follow CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

For a given .NET assembly compiled from C# (latest version), I would like to force all the string interpolations to systematically use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. Is there any way to enforce this?

Comment: You can specify if string interpolation should use the invariant culture by using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring.invariant

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329297/net-are-there-any-differences-between-invariantculture-and-en-us

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableString) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring.invariant).

Place a

```
using static System.FormattableString;
```

at the top of your code and then use like

```
string interpolated = Invariant($"My interpolated string {3.5:N2}");
```

For background information look at:

- [Interpolated strings: advanced usages](https://www.meziantou.net/interpolated-strings-advanced-usages.htm).
- [String interpolation using $ / Implicit conversions and how to specify IFormatProvider implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#implicit-conversions-and-how-to-specify-iformatprovider-implementation).